# reconnect to container as the original "docker run"

Tags: docker

I have some containers running and once in a while the connection is lost in the terminal. The container is still running perfectly. How do I reconnect to the samme user process?

The problem is:
When I do `docker exec -it name bash`, I get a new root user. But then I need to stop the applications the original user started to get them into this bash.

How do you reconnect to the original running user process/bash.

info: using mac terminal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to use the `docker attach <container ID>`

refer: `man docker-attach`

"

> The  docker  attach  command allows you to attach to a running
>   container using the container's ID or name, either to view its ongoing
>   output or to control it interactively.  You can
>          attach to the same contained process multiple times simultaneously, screen sharing style, or quickly view the progress of
>   your daemonized process.
>
> You can detach from the container (and leave it running) with CTRL-p CTRL-q (for a quiet exit) or CTRL-c which will send a SIGKILL
>   to the container.  When you are attached to a con‐
>          tainer, and exit its main process, the process's exit code will be returned to the client.

"

Answer (score 11):

```
docker ps -a                 # list all the containers and find your container
docker start <container ID>  # start the exited container 
docker attach <container ID> # attach to your container
```